# SapUI5- Tile container not working

Tags: sapui5

For some reason the tilecontainer is not working. If I place a list instead of Tiles , its working fine. I am trying to build a simple app which contains tiles.
I am new to SAPUI5. This is the code of XML.

```
<mvc:View height="100%" controllerName="sap.ui.demo.Onepage.view.App"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" displayBlock="true" xmlns="sap.m">
<App>
    <Page id="" title="Tiles" class="marginBoxContent">
        <headerContent>
            <Button icon="sap-icon://filter" />
            <Button icon="sap-icon://action-settings" />
        </headerContent>
        <subHeader>
        </subHeader>
        <content>
            <TileContainer id="container" tileDelete="handleTileDelete"
                tiles="{
                        path: '/items'
                    }">
                <StandardTile icon="sap-icon://{icon}" type="{type}"
                    number="{number}" numberUnit="{numberUnit}" title="{title}" info="{info}"
                    infoState="{infoState}" />
            </TileContainer>
        </content>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </Page>
</App>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What specifically is not working? What have you tried?

Comment: Why yo have <App> element in your XML? Please delete the <App>

Comment: The <tileContainer/> part is not working. Using the component.js i am displaying everything in <App>. Also when i replace the <tileContainer/> with <list> , its working fine.

Comment: <List
    id="list"
    items="{/items}"
    
    select="onSelect"
    growing="true"
    growingScrollToLoad="true">
    <items>
     <ObjectListItem
         
      
      
      title="{number}"
      
      numberUnit="USD">
      
     </ObjectListItem>
     
     
    </items>
   </List>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the TileContainer can be a bit tricky. You have to take care of some attributes in the parent container. Make sure your Page uses the following attribute:

```
<Page enableScrolling="false">
```

And one more pitfall could be that you´re using data binding. As long there is no object in your model at `/items` no single tile will be rendered. So either make sure that your model contains `items` and the model is assigned to your view or start testing it without binding the `tiles` property and do it static like this:

```
<mvc:View height="100%" controllerName="sap.ui.demo.Onepage.view.App"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" displayBlock="true" xmlns="sap.m">
<App>
    <Page id="" title="Tiles" class="marginBoxContent"
        enableScrolling="false">
        <headerContent>
            <Button icon="sap-icon://filter" />
            <Button icon="sap-icon://action-settings" />
        </headerContent>
        <subHeader>
        </subHeader>
        <content>
            <TileContainer id="container" tileDelete="handleTileDelete">
                <StandardTile icon="sap-icon://temperature" type="None"
                    number="23°" numberUnit="Celcius" title="Walldorf" info="Cloudy" />
            </TileContainer>
        </content>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </Page>
</App>
```

Comment: Thanks , your code works great for me. So the problem is with binding.  This is my controller: sap.ui.controller("sap.ui.demo.Onepage.view.App", {

  onInit : function (evt) {
    // set mock model
    
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("model/data.json");
    this.getView().setModel(oModel);
  }
});        Is it the right way to bind data? Because when I use it with LIST it is working. Or is there any other way for tiles?

Comment: Looks good but how´s the structure of data.json? Be aware that `/items` means the root of the model contains an array called items. For every entry in the items array data binding will be applied. Maybe [this](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/91f0f3cd6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html) helps you.

Comment: Got it! I replaced tiles="{
                        path: '/items'
                    }" with tiles="{/items}"> and its working . Thanks!

Comment: Awesome :-) I'd appreciate if you accept my answer.