# TileContainer is not displaying in IconTabFilter

Tags: sapui5

I have added a Tile Container in one of the Icon Tab Filter of my Icon Tab Bar. When I click on the filter, the tiles and tile container are missing. When I use Chrome Inspector to look into the page, it seems like the Tiles are there but it is not displayed. Any idea why?

View for the Icon Tab Bar

```
<mvc:View
controllerName="nav.controller.Main"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns="sap.m">
<IconTabBar>
    <items>
        <IconTabFilter
            icon="sap-icon://attachment"
            iconColor="Critical"
            text="Tile Container"
            count="3">
            <mvc:XMLView viewName="nav.view.TestTile" />
        </IconTabFilter>
    </items>
</IconTabBar>
```

View for the Tile Container (nav.view.TestTile)

```
<mvc:View
controllerName="nav.controller.TestTile"
displayBlock="true"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns="sap.m">
<TileContainer
    tiles="{/Tiles}">
    <StandardTile
        title="{description}"
        icon="sap-icon://process"
        number="{number}"
        numberUnit="{numberUnit}"
        info="{info}"
        infoState="{infoState}"
        press="ehTilePressed">
    </StandardTile>
</TileContainer>
```

Regards,
TM

Comment: I tried the same but obviously it´s not yet supported to put the TileContainer into a TabFilter. You can see [my suggestions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25051263/sapui5-tile-container-not-working/25052642#25052642) on using the TileContainer but they don´t help in this case. Just tried it out.

Answer (score 0):

There are two properties of sap.m.IconTabBar: **expandable and expanded**.

**expandable**: user can click the filter to toggle the collapse state of filter tab.

**expanded**: Indicates if the actual filter tab is expanded or not.

You can set set **expandable = "false" and expanded = "true"** to let the filter tab visible all the time.

Regards,
Allen

Comment: The tiles are still hidden in the IconTabFilter after I set the expandable to false for the IconTabBar. If I use a FlexBox instead of TileContainer, the tiles are displayed in the IconTabFilter but it seems like FlexBox will not automatically provides pagination if I resize the screen.

Answer (score 0):

it appearantly is a problem with the height of the tile container depending on the parent container and the parent container depending on the content ...

In my case i could do something by fixing the height of the container:

```
<TileContainer editable="false" allowAdd="false" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="myTileContainer" height="500px">
    <tiles>
        <StandardTile press="doSomething" removable="false" title="huhu" info="We are a tile"/>
        <StandardTile press="doSomething" removable="false" title="huhu" info="We are a tile"/>
        <StandardTile press="doSomething" removable="false" title="huhu" info="We are a tile"/>
        <StandardTile press="doSomething" removable="false" title="huhu" info="We are a tile"/>
    </tiles>    
</TileContainer>
```

But that is obviously not apllicable to most cases, since the height should not be fixed, since it kind of defeats most purposes.

Cheers
Michael

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue. Set the IconTabBar's **stretchContentHeight** property to true.

Check the documentation for more details
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.IconTabBar.html

Answer (score 0):

Hook on to this. The right answer is already given: the height of the parent view of the TileContainer is 0 as long as no explicit height given for the TileContainer.

I figured it out by using the element inspector.

But how to make this whole stuff more repsonsive? I am receiving items form a oData service and cannot just set a fixed height. There must be any better way. Looking for something to tell the ItemTabBar that it should completely adapt to the size of its contents. Actually it looks more like a bug to me right now.

Anyone found a better solution than just setting a fixed height?