# Implementing a Tiles layout with a component

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am trying to create a tile based layout using a component, in openui5. I am basing my code on the TileContainer sample at the [ui5 explored site](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.TileContainer/preview)

Edit: The component works, but the TileContainer/StandardTile code will not display. If I instantiate the view directly from Index.html, ignoring the component, the tiles display. If I use the Page control to wrap them in the view, it will not work. The List control, however, does display with the component, but not if I also use the Page control to wrap the list.

Are the Page and Tile controls not compatible?

I've replaced my code with my current version, this should be better able to help others as it now more directly focuses on the problem of using the component with the Tile view, instead of simpler errors I had before which I've now solved.

Edit: The problem has been resolved by using the  control in the XML view. The tiles now display correctly.

My index.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/>

<script src="../resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
    data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex">
</script>

<style >
    body, html, #content {
        height:100%;
    }
</style>

<script>
    sap.ui.localResources("my_info");
    sap.ui.localResources("view");
    sap.ui.localResources("component");
    sap.ui.localResources("data");

    var oCompCont1 = new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer("CompCont1", {
        name: "component"
    });
    oCompCont1.placeAt("content");
</script>
</head>

<body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My Component.js is:

```
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.UIComponent");
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType");
jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.Page");
jQuery.sap.declare("component.Component");

sap.ui.core.UIComponent.extend("component.Component", {

metadata: {
properties: {
  text: "string"
 }
}
});

component.Component.prototype.createContent = function(){
  this.oView = sap.ui.xmlview({id:"view1", viewName:"view.Home"});
  return this.oView;
};
```

My Component.json is:

```
{
"name": "component.Component",
"version": "0.1.0",
"description": "Tiles Component"
}
```

My Home.view.xml is:

```
<mvc:View
height="100%"
controllerName="view.Home"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns="sap.m">

//ensure you use the App control, this fixed the problem for me.
<App>
<Page
  showHeader="false"
  enableScrolling="false" >

 <TileContainer
  id="container"
  tiles="{/TileCollection}">
  <StandardTile
   icon="sap-icon://{icon}"
   title="{title}" />
 </TileContainer>
</Page>
</App>
</mvc:View>
```

My Home.controller.js is:

```
sap.ui.controller("view.Home", {

onInit : function (evt) {
 var sPath = jQuery.sap.getModulePath("data", "/tiles.json");
 var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(sPath);
 this.getView().setModel(oModel);
 }
});
```

My tiles.json is:

```
{
"TileCollection" : [
{
  "icon" : "document-text",
  "title" : "Personal Data"
},

{
  "icon" : "addresses",
  "title" : "Address Data"
},

{
  "icon" : "simple-payment",
  "title" : "Bank Details"
},

{
  "icon" : "car-rental",
  "title" : "Vehicle Details"
},

{
  "icon" : "study-leave",
  "title" : "Training and Qualifications"
}
]
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've partially fixed the problem by adding some CSS rules to explicitly define the height of the body, html and #content as height:100%. `body, html, #content {height:100%;}`
 The tiles were on the page, but the div they were in was not rendered. Hopefully this is useful to others with similar problems.

Comment: Could you please describe your problem more detailed? What exactly does not work? Are there any errors? Is something not rendered properly? See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25051263/1969374

Comment: @TimGerlach The user in the link does seem to have the same problem I have, with a List working but not Tiles, with a component. The binding works for my list, so I assume it's not an issue with the Tiles, since binding works for Tiles when I don't use the component. My problem, which I've also described in the main post, is the Tiles will not display when using a component.

Comment: So looking at the post linked by @TimGerlach, I tried wrapping my code in an App control, and this has fixed the problem.

Comment: I´m glad to hear that. As mentioned in a different post, the `sap.m.TileContainer` can be tricky sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in the comments above and according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25051263/1969374) question you should wrap your `sap.m.TileContainer` into an `sap.m.App` like this:

```
<mvc:View height="100%" controllerName="sap.ui.demo.Onepage.view.App"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" displayBlock="true" xmlns="sap.m">
<App>
    <Page
      showHeader="false"
      enableScrolling="false" >

     <TileContainer
      id="container"
      tiles="{/TileCollection}">
          <StandardTile icon="sap-icon://{icon}" title="{title}" />
     </TileContainer>
    </Page>
</App>
```

Of course the `sap.m.App` can be realized in a separate view/controller file and act as a 'root' view/controller.